# can't access the context mesh menu

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, customization

Every time i click with the RBM just appear the vertex context menu or the edge or the face context menu but never the mesh context menu and i can't resolve that problem. I try to change the keymap to Mesh-context menu in preferences, but it doesen't work.
PS: my blender version is the 3.2.0

Comment: If you are in Edit mode, the right-click menu contents will depend on whether you're in Vertex. Edge or Face selection mode. In Object mode you just have the Object Context Menu. There is no right-click Mesh context menu either in Object or Edit mode so I'm not sure what you're expecting to see.

Comment: In the tutorial i’m seeing. He can open the mesh context menu in edit mode independently if the vertex, edge or face is on selection mode but when I try it I can’t do that. So anyway, can you tell me how can i access the mesh context menu?

Comment: What tutorial are you watching (link please, including the time he does it in the tutorial if it's a long one)? - Without that I can't help!

Comment: Since version 2.80 RMB brings only vertex/edge/face contextual menus in Edit Mode. Before that, there was no contextual menus at all and RMB was by default for selecting stuff. The only Mesh menu I can remember out of memory is the one in the viewport header, but that's not a contextual menu. Please [edit] your question to provide the tutorial and timestamp where you see that menu, and ideally also post a screenshot of  that menu as you see it in the tutorial.